# Website Loading Very Slow, Each Time Different File Takes Very Long To Load

Tags: errors

My website's been very slow lately, and I've been checking my site in some of the response time checker websites. And they show over 20-30 seconds to load my website, so it is very bad right now.

The website URL is catloversmag.com.

I've noticed that each time I do a response test, there are a few files that takes forever to load. And that file changes every time.. A screenshot of the response test is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIDBC.png

I also saw some errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbHFD.png

I'm not asking anyone to fix this for me, but I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what is causing such a slow response time. I am using Mediatemple WordPress Premium hosting so I doubt it's because of my hosting. If anyone could please find out what the problem is, it would be really helpful. Even if I can't fix it myself, at least I would know what to tell if I have to use a freelancer..

This is a very important project for me and I really wish someone could help me. If someone would like to fix this personally, I would be happy to pay for the service as long as this can be fixed.

Thank you, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

While static resources "belong" to WordPress or its extensions, it's not actually involved in serving them to browser. Default WP rewrite rules completely bypass any actual existing file and let web server deal with it.

In your case it's impossible to guess what is going on from outside, but form the looks of it is more likely to be server configuration issue than WordPress one.

PS

> so I doubt it's because of my hosting

Never underestimate ability of any and every hosting to screw up.

Comment: It was running fast and well in the beginning, but after I worked on it for a few days it got slower. If I were to hire a freelancer, do you think they will be able to find the problem and fix it?

Comment: @user3117155 I would really start by going to hosting with this, it's what you [presumably] pay to have support for.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact them. But it's been blazing fast the first few days so I'm going to keep this questions open.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont have reputation to upvote. I will do so as soon as I get 15 reputation.